# PHP forcing download randomly empty files

Tags: php

I use the script below t oforce the downloading in PHP of a file (a picture, a video, etc). But sometimes, the file is empty (0 byte). It's completely random, beacause when I launch the same script, one time it's work, one time not.

```
$full_path = 'path_to_my_file'; // chemin système (local) vers le fichier
$file_name = basename($full_path);

ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
$date = gmdate(DATE_RFC1123);

$path = parse_url($full_path, PHP_URL_PATH);
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $path;

header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');

header('Content-Tranfer-Encoding: none');
header('Content-MD5: '.base64_encode(md5_file($full_path)));
header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($path).'; name="'.$file_name.'"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');

header('Date: '.$date);
header('Expires: '.gmdate(DATE_RFC1123, time()+1));

readfile($full_path);
exit;
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks

EDIT: One precision, when I say "one time it's work, one time not", I mean everytime with the same file to download. So, the file exists and sometime it works, some time it doesn't.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a **quickly** manner? Can you check whether your file exists by using `file_exists()` and if it is readable by using `is_readable()` for example, when you get that 0byte file?

Comment: Please check file with file_exists() function to verify whether file exist or not

Comment: The file exists in any case, the proove is that the downloaded file (empty or not) as the same name that the original one